# Can I get the content of this parameter just using bash?

Tags: regex, bash

If I have the content below generated from `wpa_passphrase` stored in the variable `wpa_psk` can I get the content of `psk` using just bash or do I need to use `sed` or something like it?

```
network={ 
    ssid="ssid" 
    psk=13ddde5c993709218f02296c238df70579dc392cc216c02356b483a2c2278187 
}
```

Comment: Umm... `sed` is bash?

Comment: @Andrew `sed` is an external command.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know, but I feel like if its something that can be used in a bash script and the terminal why would you consider it not bash?

Comment: @Andrew Have a look at the `bash` manual and search for `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
part=${wpa_passphrase/*psk=/}
psk=${part/??\}/}
```

First one will remove everything before and including `psk=` and the second one will remove `}` and the space and newline before it.

Answer (score 1):

Without external commands, as asked for:

```
IFS=$'\n= '
while read -r lhs rhs; do
    if [[ "$lhs" == "psk" ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$rhs"
        break
    fi
done
```

This loop will read lines from standard input and split them on `=`. The `lhs` variable will get the left hand side of the `=` and `rhs` will get the right hand side.

If `$lhs` is `psk` we print `$rhs` to standard output and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^[[:blank:]]+psk=(.*)/\1/p' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt                                 
network={ 
    ssid="ssid" 
    psk=13ddde5c993709218f02296c238df70579dc392cc216c02356b483a2c2278187 
}

$ sed -nE 's/^[[:blank:]]+psk=(.*)/\1/p' file.txt
13ddde5c993709218f02296c238df70579dc392cc216c02356b483a2c2278187
```